# How to make my pc go into black screen of death/blue screen?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, bsod

Please, is there any way that I can let this happen in a virtualbox? I just want to experience it and try to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the registry and delete the following key:

**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Ntfs`**

Restart and instant BSOD.

[image]

Completely fixable, if you know how!

Comment: is the fix the same as the fix in the genuine bsod?

Comment: Yes it is.  This is a genuine BSOD after caused by corruption of the registry.  This can happen in a normal machine, should any piece of software go completely crazy and start spring cleaning the registry of its own accord.  The method you use to recover from it uses a pretty standard Windows tool, but from a special place and can be applicable to many other BSOD's.  You'll see why and how once you figure out the fix.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can [force one with the keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266483.aspx), but it doesn't take much fixing.

The problem is, fixing one BSOD is totally different to fixing another, and most are caused by hardware problems! Getting a reliable software based BSOD in virtualbox should be difficult, and I don't believe you can boot a VHD with one of the tools one would normally use.

Comment: +1 for BSODs being completely different from one another.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Russinovich's **[screen saver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897558.aspx)** is an easy way to 'experience' a variety of BSODs ... and easy to fix too, just move the mouse :)

Seriously, just because you may be able to reproduce a BSOD, doesn't mean the fix you may find is the universal solution for the problem. Get Nirsoft's **[BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html)** and you'll have a powerful tool to analyze a BSOD when it occurs.

Comment: yeah thanks, I'll definitely try this, but I won't accept this as the answer yet. I'll still wait for more answers:)